# Get the formatting of a cell in an Excel 2010 template

Tags: c#, excel

Im generating an Excel 2010 report based on a template in code using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

I need to grab the formatting from a cell in the template and apply it on subsequent cells down the column. To simplify, I want my cells to be right justified. Maybe its faster to specify this explicitly in code but I would prefer if I could base formatting on the template and not hardcode a particular style.

<strike>I am using `workSheet.get_Range("L2", Type.Missing).get_Resize(1, 1)` to select the cell.</strike>
Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: how the question title relates to its content?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Where does the array even come into it?

Comment: I basically need an accessor to the formatting of the cell @NirMH. Using `workSheet.get_Range("L2", Type.Missing).get_Resize(1, 1)` I have been able to access cells for other purposes, however this may not apply in this situation @Mr. Disappointment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where `get_Range()` comes into the picture.  I usually just get a `Range` directly.

I think what you are after is something to this effect (filler code there so you can see the variable names):

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim AlignType As Long

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("MySheet.xlsx")
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    AlignType = oSheet.Range("G1").HorizontalAlignment
    oSheet.Range("G1:G" & oSheet.Range("G1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row).HorizontalAlignment = AlignType
```

Change the ranges to suit your own code.

Basically, read the value out (it's an enum, so you don't need to get the actual setting, just its number), and write it back into the other cells.  You could probably do it all in one step, I separated it for clarity.

Comment: Tested and Works. Much thanks! `.HorizontalAlignment` was what I was looking for! I think `Range()` is VBA, `get_range()` is c#. Thanks again

Comment: @robot no problem.  I did that in C#, actually, but glad it worked.